# Programmatically save an image to xcassets in Swift

Tags: image, swift

Say my app downloads an image, is it possible to save this to Images.xcassets programmatically, so that the image doesn't have to be downloaded again? 
Or would the best option be to keep retrieving it from the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't save it to the images.assets. However you can save it to the document directory buy doing this. (Code from here - [How to convert code objective c to Swift to save image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301424/how-to-convert-code-objective-c-to-swift-to-save-image))

```
let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true) {
if paths.count > 0 {
    if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String {
        let readPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Image.png")
        let image = UIImage(named: readPath)
        let writePath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Image2.png") 
        UIImagePNGRepresentation(image).writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What would the code be then retrieve it?

Comment: I believe the `image` variable stores the image so if you want to do anything with it be sure to use that :D

Answer (score 5):

You can't save to `Images.xcassets`, however you can save it to a file and access it with `imageWithContentsOfFile:`.

You could also use a caching library, like [JGAFImageCache](https://github.com/jaminguy/JGAFImageCache) or [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke).

Answer (score 5):

you can't write to the bundle  at all you need to save the data to you documents/caches folder inside your sandbox